# I need cmd output and errors to be posted on a textblock at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, runtime

Currently I have a command that does this. First, upon the button click event I execute a batch file and then I will create a new text file by saving the log, results and erros into the text file. I would like to create a textblock so that this textblock would shows these results and errors at during the process of running the batch file. Is it possible?

My current code for writing into a text file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process runantc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

runantc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\GUI\\batch.bat";

runantc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
runantc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
runantc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
runantc.Start();

string procOutput = runantc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string procError = runantc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();


// create a writer and open the file
TextWriter outputlog = new StreamWriter("C:\\GUI\\processoutput.txt");
outputlog.Write(procOutput);
outputlog.Close();

// create a writer and open the file
TextWriter outputerror = new StreamWriter("C:\\GUI\\error.txt");
outputerror.Write(procError);
outputerror.Close();
```

Edit 1:
I understand the code:

```
string procOutput = runantc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

reads out the output from start to end, not during run process so I think my question is to ask whether if I can replace this with something so that I can see it at runtime

Comment: What is it doing vs. what you are expecting it to do? Please be specific.

Comment: i think i mentioned i need to see the process of batch.bat at run time.. so i need the command lines to be printed out into a  textblock. i will clarify if u still have doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, in addition to writing the output to a log file, while the process is actually running, you'd like to display the output/errors to a textblock, basically allowing you to watch the process's output as it's executing. Is that right? I have not personally done this, but if it's what you want to do, then you should look at listening to the output/error asynchronously, and setting up an event handler that the proc will call when it writes output or errors. See the [documentation on BeginErrorReadline at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginerrorreadline.aspx) and also [documentation on ErrorDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx) A similar event handler exists for output.